# Error while installing postfix on CentOS 6

Tags: centos, postfix, yum

I want to install postfix on CentOS 6 but I get the following error :

```
yum install postfix -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Setting up Install Process
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ftp, http[s] or file.
 Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/x86_64/6/base/mirrorlist.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this ? Does it have anything to do with people saying CentOS 6 is dead ? Is there any fix ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CentOS 6 went completely [end of life on November 30](https://wiki.centos.org/About/Product).
Therefore, you won't be able to patch, or install any new software.

The only exception to this would be if you were to convert your system to RHEL 6, and purchase [Red Hat Extended Life Cycle Support](https://access.redhat.com/articles/4665701).

I wouldn't even recommend that, however.
You should upgrade to CentOS 7, or even CentOS 8 instead.

Comment: Is a direct upgrade possible from 6 to 7 or should I install 7 and move everything manually?

Comment: A direct upgrade is possible, yes. However, I would personally choose to do a manual migration on a fresh install.

Comment: If you end up with CentOS 6.x is there any upgrade path to 7 and 8. From what I have heard you need to backup install new CentOS 7,8 and restore. > There is no more official support for upgrade CentOS 6 --> 7
> https://centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=69363#p291370
> > And the UpgradeTool was removed:
> https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CentOSUpgradeTool

Answer (score 7):

While CentOS 6 is truly dead, and the ultimate fix is upgrading, you can still install packages by using the Vault repositories as detailed [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol).

To quickly fix up your CentOS 6 so you can `yum install` things, run:

```
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```